# Real advantage of ThreadLocal versus new local variable

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

I realize that ThreadLocal has been visited several times, esp with the SimpleDateFormat examples.

But it seems that even by making SDF 'ThreadLocal', we are still making one instance of SDF() per thread, that is equivalent to calling a new SDF().

Doing this once gives one copy of SDF to each thread -

```
ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> sdf = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>();
```

And so does this -

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
```

The thread safety is simply created by making a copy of SDF every time.
So we have same number of SDF instances in both cases.

So, where is the improvement in terms of number of instances?

If there is none - why would i use ThreadLocal, and not just do new SDF() every time in the thread? That way i dont worry about synchronization either.

If this argument is correct - one reason i see to use ThreadLocal is the scope of it. That it can be .get() later somewhere else in the code, without passing it around in parameters.

I wanted to make sure, i am understanding this correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: What `SimpleDateFormatter` do you mean? No such class in JDK. May be `SimpleDateFormat`? But what  thread-safety you mean regarding `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: Sorry i fixed the typo now - SimpleDateFormat, that is.

Comment: @Ivan Pronin SimpleDateFormat wasn't thread-safe (I think, Oracle fixed it lately). Having one public static final SDF used by multiple threads could lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Well i am saying just do a new SDF() per thread. Not a final static SDF that is shared across threads. How is ThreadLocal SDF() better than new SDF(), when both create a new() instance.

Comment: IMO, the only use for `ThreadLocal` is when you have old library code that keeps state in `static` variables, and you want to use the library in more than one thread at the same time.  It's mostly easy to replace each `static Foobar foo` with a `static ThreadLocal<Foobar> foo`.

Comment: your understanding is correct.

Comment: @jameslarge well just say, new oldLibraryClass(). You see. This will give you  a separate oldLibraryClass obj, with no problems across threads.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov thanks

Comment: Actually, besides the scope of ThreadLocal, i can see one more reason to use it. Lets say theres an object I must share between threads, and so is global or supplied by some wrapper class. Now only one or two fields in this object can be mutated by the threads, and other are to be shared. I could make just those fields ThreadLocal, so each thread can see their own version.

Comment: Note that classes like `Date` or `SimpleDateFormat` are **legacy** now. They got replaced by the new date-API inside the `java.time` package.

Comment: You should not be using the legacy date-time classes such as `SimpleDateFormat`. Now supplanted by the thread-safe java.time classes where this Question is moot. See the `DateTimeFormatter` class.

Comment: @Zabuza and Basil, yes, i am looking into them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ThreadLocals have a number of uses but in the context of wrapping a non-thread-safe object consider the following example.
The non-thread-local method will most likely crash, while the thread local version won't.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    MyParser parser = new MyParser();
    IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().forEach(i-> parser.parseTl("20170816"));
    IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().forEach(i-> parser.parse("20170816"));
}

static class MyParser {
    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> sdftl =
            ThreadLocal.withInitial(()-> new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"));

    public Date parse(String str) {
        try {
            return sdf.parse(str);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Date parseTl(String str) {
        try {
            return sdftl.get().parse(str);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you could simply construct a new formatter each time you want to parse a date:

```
public Date parse(String str) {
    try {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

But the problem with this approach is that constructing `SimpleDateFormat` is a relatively slow operation so you want to construct it a minimal amount of times.

There are of course other options in this case, you could synchronize access to the formatter, but that could be much slower than each thread having its own copy.
Or you could use the Java 8 `java.time` formatters which are thread safe.